# Getting an error with make

Tags: c, makefile, automake

I'm a newbie on using make files and other GNU make tools. I'm working on this project called axis2/c which uses the automake toolchain. I'm running into this compile error.

```
    Making all in description
    /bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../src/core/engine -I../../../util/include -I../../../axiom/include -I../../../neethi/include  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DAXIS2_GUTHTHILA_ENABLED  -DAXIS2_JSON_ENABLED -DAXIS2_SVR_MULTI_THREADED  -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g -D_GNU_SOURCE -DAXIS2_GUTHTHILA_ENABLED  -DAXIS2_JSON_ENABLED -DAXIS2_SVR_MULTI_THREADED -MT op.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/op.Tpo -c -o op.lo op.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../include -I../../../src/core/engine -I../../../util/include -I../../../axiom/include -I../../../neethi/include -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -DAXIS2_GUTHTHILA_ENABLED -DAXIS2_JSON_ENABLED -DAXIS2_SVR_MULTI_THREADED -g -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -ansi -Wall -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g -D_GNU_SOURCE -DAXIS2_GUTHTHILA_ENABLED -DAXIS2_JSON_ENABLED -DAXIS2_SVR_MULTI_THREADED -MT op.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/op.Tpo -c op.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/op.o
    op.c: In function 'axis2_op_get_axis_specific_mep_const':
    op.c:783: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_IN_OUT_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:783: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    op.c:783: error: for each function it appears in.)
    op.c:788: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_IN_ONLY_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:793: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_IN_OPTIONAL_OUT_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:798: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_OUT_IN_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:803: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_OUT_ONLY_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:808: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_OUT_OPTIONAL_IN_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:813: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_ROBUST_IN_ONLY_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    op.c:818: error: 'AXIS2_MEP_URI_ROBUST_OUT_ONLY_WSDL2' undeclared (first use in this function)
    make[4]: *** [op.lo] Error 1
    make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These constants are in a file called axis2_const.h, so I went into op.c and specifically included that (This is a redundant steps). But, I'm still getting this compilation error.

Any idea how I would solve this?

Note: Let me know if I need to include more information.

Comment: The constants may be in the header you're including, but unless you know otherwise I would check to ensure they are not being stripped out by a preprocesor macro block (`#ifdef BLAHBLAH ...defines your symbols... #endif`). yo umay just be missing something simple that allows them to be pulled in. Use The Source, Luke.